# delphi DirectoryListBox Get selected directory name

Tags: directory

I'm using a dirListBox in delphi. I cant get the sub directory name of the directory selected. It gives me the root direct name instead. How do I get the selected directory name?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

dirListBox.Directory returns the parent directory, not subdirectory.

The only way I could get the correct names was using the itemindex.
The itemindex is updated when you click or move the cursor to the directory.

```
 fMain.eProject.Text:=fProject.dirlistBox.Items[fProject.dirListBox.ItemIndex];
 fMain.ePath.Text:=fProject.dirListBox.GetItemPath(fProject.dirListBox.ItemIndex);
```